# Specific input values convert to JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

Following form input values need to convert in JSON using Jquery, I will update this JSON data into mysql via AJAX. I need to convert specific input values (e.g: product id, product name, product price, discount reason, discount amount) to JSON format. I have tried myself:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var jsons = $('form').serializeJSON();
  console.log( jsons );
});
```

But, I can't maintain sequence and can't skip unwanted inputs.

**PHP CODE:**

```
    <form>
        First name: <input type="text" name="first_name" value="Addem"> 
        Last name: <input type="text" name="last_name" value="Smith"><br><br>
        Product id: <input type="number" name="items[][cat_id]" value="18"><br><br>
        Product name: <input type="text" name="items[][product_name]" value="Men's t-shirt"><br><br>
        Product sku: <input type="text" name="item_sku" value="PBKL09509403"><br><br>
        Date: <input type="text" name="date" value="2018-09-18"><br><br>
        Product price: <input type="text" name="items[][product_price]" value="165.00"><br><br>
        Discount reason: <input type="text" name="adjustments[][reason]" value="Special"> 
        Discount amount: <input type="text" name="adjustments[][amount]" value="20.00"><br><br>
        Product total: <input type="text" name="total[price]" value="145.00"><br><br>
    </form>
```

**JSON Output (required):**

```
{  
   "items":[  
      {  
         "cat_id":18,
         "product_name":"Men's t-shirt",
         "product_price":165
      }
   ],
   "total":{  
      "price":145
   },
   "adjustments":[  
      {  
         "reason":"Special",
         "amount":"20"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Is `ca_id` supposed to be `cat_id`?

Comment: Are you sure you need JSON? If you just use `$("form").serialize()` it will create URL-encoded parameters that match your structure.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake. It will be `cat_id`

Comment: PHP doesn't support JSON parameters directly, but it can get those parameters from `$_POST` if you use `serialize()`.

Comment: And `total` should be `subtotal`?

Comment: Yes, I am sure I need JSON. I know PHP doesn't support JSON directly. I have done an example on `codepen.io`. There I have done it with PHP and JS. Actually, I need to convert specific input data to JSON. Please read the my description.

Comment: What's wrong with the result in the codepen?

Comment: You can simply remove the unwanted inputs. `delete jsons.first_name;`

Comment: Good man. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the unwanted inputs, you can use the `delete` operator.

```
var jsons = $("form").serializeJSON();
delete jsons.first_name;
delete jsons.last_name;
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't maintain the sequence properly. If that's true, it sounds like a bug in the `serializeJSON` plugin that you're using. There may be other implementations that work better.

Comment: I have found a solution for maintain the JSON sequence. When I change the form inputs location as per json sequence then it's solved. I mean that, form inputs need to sorted as `First name, Last name, Product id, Product name, Product sku, Date, Product price, Product total, Discount reason, Discount amount`. Also, delete unwanted inputs.

Comment: I thought you meant that the order of items in an array was different from their order on the page. JavaScript objects don't guarantee order of properties, and nothing usually depends on it.

Comment: But, it works for me while I set form inputs order same as json array.

Comment: Yes, even though there's no guarantee, some implementations happen to remember the order. You should just be careful about writing applications that depend on it, it might not work the same in all browsers.

Comment: You should use arrays when order matters, use objects just for name-to-value mapping.

Comment: May you properly don't know about `.serializeJSON()`. Please find the documentation from the link https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON. Also, I have found another option for skip the unwanted inputs which is `:skip` of this `.serializeJSON()` method.

Comment: The documentation is clear: **The serializeJSON function returns a JavaScript object, not a JSON String. The plugin should probably have been called serializeObject or similar, but those plugins already existed.** So it doesn't actually create the JSON, you have to call `JSON.stringify()` for that.

Comment: But my point is that the plugin can't force the order of anything, since it's just creating a JavaScript object. If the JS object doesn't remember the order of properties, `serializeJSON` can't fix that.